# Google Analytics/Firebase - Creating an email alert when an error screen is showing?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I want to be aware of when key issues/errors happening frequently in my Android app so I can intervene immediately.

Has anyone discovered a way to set more custom alerting in GA or Firebase so that if an event is triggering over a certain count threshold, I get an email alert?

I see a way to do this (https://meganvwalker.com/ga-creating-custom-alerts-in-google-analytics/), but seems it's only supported for Web (https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/13279940/don-t-have-view-column?hl=en), so I'm looking for another option.